# python - get response 200 at first, then 401 when looping through URLs with requests.get()

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm scraping NHL game data for multiple games - which are all in different URLs - using requests.get(). The code works fine and I can get the data and get response = 200, but when I loop through the URL's using the unique gameIds, I eventually get response = 401 if the loop gets too large. Is there something that can be done about this without sacrificing the time it takes to run the code?

```
gameIds=['2022020022','2022020028','2022020044','2022020072','2022020088'] #can be much larger list


#function to get data from web
def get_data(gameId): 
   url=f'https://api-web.nhle.com/v1'
   proxies={}
   verify=''
   headers={}
   response=requests.get(url + f'/gamecenter/{gameId}/play-by-play')
   
   if response.status_code == 200:
      data=response.json()
      return data

   else:
      print('status code <> 200, status code is ' + str(response.status_code))

all_data=[] #empty list to append each game's data
for i in gameIds:
   data=get_data(i)
   all_data.append(data)
```

NOTE: I have added proxies=, headers=, and verify= to requests.get(), but I can't share those here for privacy reasons.

I know my code works because I've gotten the desired results for a small sample, but there must be something I'm missing as to why I'm eventually getting a 401 response

Comment: Did you check the api documentation of api-web.nhle.com?

Comment: @GandalfRahmberg there is no api documentation for this website. It's a known pain point for people scraping the NHL data.

Comment: I see. How large is the gameIds?

Comment: @GandalfRahmberg it can be any length. I'm trying to run one season's worth of games which is 82. I've gotten response=401 from as early as the 10th iteration of the loop or sometimes it will run for 60+ gameIds before returning 401. I don't know much about what's actually happening in when I run requests.get() , so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you have examples of game IDs that result in HTTP 401 ? All of those in the question reveal results

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) is used specifically for that purpose. It should not be used for anything else. Having said that, a poor implementation in the backend could return bogus / inappropriate HTTP status codes.

Let's assume that 401 is being returned for certain game IDs and that, maybe, retrying after some delay might help.

You could consider doing something like this:

```
from requests import get
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

MAX_RETRIES = 5
DELAY = 10

gameIds = ["2022020022", "2022020028", "2022020044", "2022020072", "2022020088"]
all_data = []


def process(gameId: str) -> tuple[dict, str]:
    rv = {}, ""
    try:
        url = f"https://api-web.nhle.com/v1/gamecenter/{gameId}/play-by-play"
        with get(url) as response:
            match response.status_code:
                case 200:
                    rv = response.json(), gameId
                case 401:
                    pass
                case _:
                    response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unable to retrieve data for {gameId} due to {e}")
    return rv


for _ in range(MAX_RETRIES):
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        for data, gameId in pool.imap_unordered(process, gameIds.copy()):
            if data:
                all_data.append(data)
                gameIds.remove(gameId)
    if not gameIds:
        break
    print(f"Delaying for {DELAY}s")
    sleep(DELAY)

if gameIds:
    print("Unable to acquire data for ", gameIds)
else:
    # all_data is now ready for use
    print("All good")
```

The idea here is that each successfully acquired gameId is removed from the input list. We repeat the acquisition process up to MAX_RETRIES retries with a delay of DELAY seconds between each iteration for as long as the gameIds list is not empty

Answer (score -1):

So here are two possible issues and solutions:

1. You are getting **401(Unauthorized)** error for only certain game ids

   Solution: Store the unauthorized game ids in separate files and you can double check.
2. If 401 issue is because of too many requests, you can use the cache to fix this issue.

   Solution: When you get 401 issue, store the game ids (success ids) in a variable. Wait for some time (like 30 seconds) and continue the script but ignore the game ids (success ids)

Here is the retry decorator:

import logging
import random

```
import sys
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def retry_with_backoff(retries: int = 3, backoff_in_secs: int = 1):
    def fn(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            attempt = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    LOGGER.error("failed execution", exc_info=sys.exc_info())
                    if attempt == retries:
                        LOGGER.info(f"max retries ({retries}) reached")
                        raise
                    else:
                        sleep = (backoff_in_secs * 2 ** attempt + random.uniform(0, 1))
                        LOGGER.debug(f"backoff sleep {sleep}")
                        time.sleep(sleep)
                        attempt += 1

        return wrapper

    return fn
```

How to use the above decorator:

```
@retry_with_backoff(retries=2, backoff_in_secs=30)
def retrieve_data(url: str):
    # your code
    # requests.get(url)
```

Comment: If you need, I can provide you the code of **retry** decorator.

Comment: that would be helpful!

Comment: I'm posting it as an answer as I'm not able to post codebase as a comment

Comment: I added it to my answer and please check it.

Comment: If the 401 error is issued because the request is unauthorised then what's the point in retrying?

Comment: If we get 401 error for certain game ids, we just skip it and continue. We are not retrying.

Comment: @GandalfRahmberg is that why your decorator is called *retry_with_backoff* ?

Comment: The decorator is for option-2 when there are too many requests.

Comment: so using my example, I would have to build this into my get_data() function rather than the loop?

Comment: @GandalfRahmberg I'm confused. Why would HTTP 401 be raised for too many requests when HTTP 429 is available?

Comment: @n_cen Yes and you need to add a check if a game id is already lopped or not.

Comment: @Codist I know we have 429 code for Too Many Requests but as api-web.nhle.com does not have API documentation and we can not make sure. That's why I suggested retry mechanism